# UIActionSheet in iPad appears with arrow on bottom

Tags: ios, ipad, view, uiactionsheet, cgrect

I am adding a `UIActionSheet` control on button click within `UITableViewCell`s. The action sheet appears with downward arrow always unless until there is less space available above the bounding view.

I want the actionsheet to appear below the bounding view whenever there's space available.

Anyone knows any solution to make the default appearance of `UIActionSheet` with upward arrow?

Here is the code of adding `UIActionSheet` which is btw working fine:

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                         delegate:self
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                           destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                otherButtonTitles:@"Edit", @"Delete", @"New", @"Copy", nil];

[actionSheet showFromRect:[self.headerView bounds]
                   inView:self.contentView
                 animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

`UIActionSheet` is deprecated in iOS 8. To create and manage action sheets in iOS 8 and later, instead use [UIAlertController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertController_class/index.html) with a preferredStyle of UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet. You can use `UIPopoverPresentationController` and its `permittedArrowDirections` to set the arrow direction.

Answer (score 0):

Check this section in the [`UIActionSheet Documentation`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiactionsheet_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIActionSheet/showInView%3a). If that does not works for you, you can always create a custom `UIView` with custom content :)

Comment: I already know about methods and properties of UIActionSheet. And I also know that I can create custom views. But I don't want to use custom controls when ios has already given built-in controls..